# How to annotate a C# function to say that a parameter is not null if it returns

Tags: c#, .net

I have some validation code that throws an exception if a string is null/empty/blank.  I'd like for it to signal to the null checking system that `argument` is not null after the function returns.

```
void ThrowIfNullEmptyOrBlank(string? argument, string paramName)
    => ThrowIf(Check.Null & Check.Empty & Check.Blank, argument, paramName);
```

`[return: NotNull] void ThrowIfNullEmptyOrBlank(string? argument, string paramName)` isn't right, 'cause my method doesn't return the value (I suppose I could change that, but it's cleaner this way).

Is it possible to do what I'm trying?

Comment: How about:

    string ThrowIfNullEmptyOrBlank(string? argument, string paramName)
    {
        ThrowIf(Check.Null & Check.Empty & Check.Blank, argument, paramName);
        return argument;
    }     . The compiler will know the output is not null and you can use that

Comment: Dotnet uses the MaybeNullWhenAttribute, but that is internal

Comment: That first suggestion requires callers to set `argument` to the result of this call for the type data to propagate; I'd rather not rely on people remembering to do that.

Comment: You might want to consider splitting the logic for "checking" the value with "throwing". `IsNullOrWhitespace` also already exists which uses `[NotNullWhen]`, which only works because the `Is...` method returns a boolean.

Comment: `IsNullOrWhitespace` is actually null/empty/whitespace, which is _not_ what I'm looking for in some checks that call this.  I considered giving a special condition to call that prebuilt method if all three flags are set, but decided against it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `NotNullAttribute`:

```cs
void ThrowIfNullEmptyOrBlank([NotNull] string? argument, string paramName)
    => ThrowIf(Check.Null & Check.Empty & Check.Blank, argument, paramName);
```

From [Attributes for null-state static analysis interpreted by the C# compiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/attributes/nullable-analysis):

> A nullable parameter, field, property, or return value will never be null.

Which matches the goal - `argument` will never be null if method returns.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74625611/2501279) also can be useful (also check out the `CallerArgumentExpressionAttribute` trick).

Comment: I thought I'd tried that, but I think I'd applied the annotation to the wrong method during my checking.  Thanks for making me take a second look!